# How can I speed up adding many ggplot layers/geoms in a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, plot, gridextra

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

Nbars = 2

generate_eg_data <- function() {
  eg_data = data.table(LL = 0:99, UL = 1:100, val = sort(runif(100, 0, 1)))
  eg_data[, valColor := val %>% multiply_by(255) %>% ceiling %>% as.hexmode %>% list %>% c(., ., .) %>% do.call(paste0, .) %>% paste0("#", .)]
  return(eg_data)
}

lst_eg_data <- lapply(seq(Nbars), function(i) {
  return(generate_eg_data())
})

p <- ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, Nbars + 1)) +
  theme_classic()
for (i in seq(Nbars)) {
  for (j in seq(nrow(lst_eg_data[[i]]))) {
    p %<>% add(geom_ribbon(data = lst_eg_data[[i]][j, .(x = c(LL, UL), ymin = rep(i - 0.25, 2), ymax = rep(i + 0.25, 2))],
                           aes(x = x, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
                           fill = lst_eg_data[[i]][j, valColor]))
  }
}
p
```

The above should be sufficient in demonstrating the outcomes I want. For simplicity, in the above I have generated similar `valColor` for each bar, but in reality each bar varies a lot with different RGB combinations (i.e. not only greyscale).

The code works, but it is just too slow, because in fact I have 6 bars in each plot and 36 of such plots together with some other auxiliary layers which I would like to put altogether in a single plot with the help of `gridExtra::arrangeGrob`. The process has been running more than an hour and it is not done yet.

I am wondering if it is because I am trying to add each bar using 100 separate layers. If so, is it possible to add each bar as a single layer, while retaining the unique coloring scheme defined for each bar? Or there are other reasons for the slow plots and how can I make it more efficient? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop slows the whole thing down, and it is not necessary, bad style, and should be avoided.
Rather, the outer loop (`i`) should be matched to a y-aesthetic, and the inner loop (`j`) should be matched to an x-aesthetic.
(Apart from that, one would usually use rather something like `p <- p + geom_ribbon()` instead of `%<>%`.)

Here is an approach using `geom_tile()`, but other geoms may be appropriate as well.
Note that I turn your list of two dataframes (`lst_eg_data`) into a single dataframe first.

```r
df1 <- melt(lst_eg_data, id.vars = names(lst_eg_data[[1]]))

ggplot(df1, aes(x = LL, y = L1, fill = valColor, height = .5)) +
    scale_fill_grey() +
    geom_tile(show.legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually need user specified colors but I guess I can achieve it by using `scale_fill_manual()`. I will try tomorrow and update.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well.  Unfortunately I can't map my loop info to an aesthetic, as I'm using it to adjust jitter in geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = x))).  Any other suggestions?